# Cannot get to the screw behind disconnect switch

Tags: switch, circuit-breaker, screws, accessibility

I'm trying to unscrew what "seems" to be (I'm not an expert) a heat pump disconnect switch. I don't know the function of this box. It's also connected to the furnace (see pictures). Box is screwed on the 2x4. Problem I have is I cannot get to the screw in the box to remove it. Do you know what can be done to get access to the screw?[image] It seems that I have to remove in some way the black plastic cover in the box but I don't know how.[image]

Comment: What is your purpose for removing the cover?

Comment: I can’t quite see the screw you are talking about but after after installing , I can tell how many of these in the hundreds they have to be in the off position and the “shorting bar or connecting contacts” removed then under this at the top of the shield there is a screw that retains the top of the lower plastic shield. I may be wrong but after hundreds of these inexpensive disconnects they need to be off and or removed to access the screw to get to the terminals.

Comment: @jwh20 the purpoe for removing the cover was to get access to the screws that attach the box to the wall

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think the screw has nothing to do with removing the dead front. Think this is how:

Turn the switch to OFF.

Lift up the top plastic section using the holes on the side. This will allow lifting or prying the bottom section over the stop on the bottom.

But it may be that you just pry on the bottom in the central slot.

Comment: You're right. I had to pry on the bottom in the central slot (with a screwdriver for example) and the cover popped up. Thank you to you and Ed for your help!

Answer (score 5):

To get access you have to pull the shorting bar then you can get to the screw and pop the cover off.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ed! Can you explain me what is the shorting bar and how am I supposed to pull it? Manually? And when I pull it, I can get to a screw that when unscrewed let me remove the cover, right? So finally I can get access to the back screw? Sorry if I need so much details!

Comment: I can’t see your panel well on my phone but, I have seen and installed many , inexpensive disconnects, most have to have or be pulled out to disable , if flipped over they will go in in the off position. Once pulled out or in the off position the screw to release the shield is at the top.

Comment: Searching on the internet, I think that I see what you mean Ed. You probably refer to a disconnect switch of this type right? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgtsswuZPnY Mine is of this type (it's not a Siemens but it looks like it very much): https://www.amazon.com/Siemens-WNAS2060-Non-Automatic-Switch-Disconnect/dp/B0052MCOIM

Comment: Ok I could not see the switch I thought it was a shorting bar style.